# how to compare varchar value in SQL server management studio

Tags: compare, ssms, varchar

I can compare the values of varchar by using "LIKE" . For example

```
 CompanyName like 'google'
```

how can I compare it for dissimilarity. i.e, I want do 'companyName' is not equal to "google". How can I do it??

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Have you tried googling "sql not equal to"? What didn't you find?

Comment: I tried to work like companyName != 'google'. It did not worked as it is not an integer . Then I worked with '>' operator. It worked but its not good to use as we are not comparing it in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NOT operator to achieve this:

```
CompanyName not like '%google%'
```